# Power stage for VCR (Voltage Controlled Resistor)

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, voltage-controlled-resistor

I'm building a VCR (Voltage Controlled Resistor) using the LM13700 component. You can read more details on that here:

[Floating voltage-controlled resistor with LM13700: How does it work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389347/floating-voltage-controlled-resistor-with-lm13700-how-does-it-work)

The problem I'm facing is its severe current constraints: below 1 mA <sup>(*)</sup>. Therefore, I'm building my own "output stage" for the VCR.

<sub>(*) Note: The output current of the darlingtons in the LM13700 is up to 20mA. However, it is the output of the OTA's (Operational Transconductance Amplifier) that define the current capabilities of the VCR (Voltage Controlled Resistor) circuit.</sub>

## 1.  The circuit

I've designed the following circuit to create a more powerful (read: more current capable) output stage for my VCR:

[image]

Let us analyse the circuit. Note that the circuit behaves differently for **V<sub>IN1</sub>** > **V<sub>IN2</sub>** versus **V<sub>IN2</sub>** > **V<sub>IN1</sub>**. So we'll handle both situations.

#### 1.1  **V<sub>IN1</sub>** > **V<sub>IN2</sub>**

Thanks to the schottky diodes **D<sub>1</sub>** and **D<sub>2</sub>**, only the mosfet on the left **T<sub>1</sub>** can conduct current if **V<sub>IN1</sub>** > **V<sub>IN2</sub>**.

The positive input of the opamp **V<sub>IN+</sub>** is the result of a resistive division. The higher the voltage difference **ΔV<sub>IN</sub>** on the terminals, the higher **V<sub>IN+</sub>** rises. We want the current **I<sub>2</sub>** (going through the mosfet) to rise accordingly. Will that happen?
If **I<sub>2</sub>** is "too low", the feedback to the negative input of the opamp **V<sub>IN-</sub>** is lower than **V<sub>IN+</sub>**, causing the opamp output to increase. This makes mosfet **T<sub>1</sub>** more conductive (gate rises), so **I<sub>2</sub>** goes up. This keeps happening until **V<sub>IN-</sub>** reaches the level of **V<sub>IN+</sub>**.

I've made following calculations:

[image]

From which we can deduct that:

[image]

We have proven here a *linear relation* between **ΔV<sub>IN</sub>** and **I<sub>2</sub>**. Sure, that's not the only current flowing between the terminals. But we assume that **I<sub>2</sub>** >> **I<sub>1</sub>**, such that:

[image]

The green box encircles the total (perceived) resistance from one terminal to the other.

#### 1.2  **V<sub>IN2</sub>** > **V<sub>IN1</sub>**

The currents **I<sub>1</sub>** and **I<sub>2</sub>** now flow in the opposite direction. Only mosfet **T<sub>2</sub>** on the right can conduct (thanks to the schottky's).

[image]

The positive input of the opamp **V<sub>IN+</sub>** is of course still the result of a resistive division. But this time its value *goes down* with increasing **ΔV<sub>IN</sub>**. Well, at least if you keep **V<sub>IN2</sub>** fixed and only pull at **V<sub>IN1</sub>** to increase the differential **ΔV<sub>IN</sub>**.
For the feedback to work correctly, we hope that **I<sub>2</sub>** increases in magnitude as **ΔV<sub>IN</sub>** grows. Does that happen?

Yes, it does. As **V<sub>IN+</sub>** decreases, it slides below the value of **V<sub>IN-</sub>**. The opamp output takes a dive. The PMOS **T<sub>2</sub>** gains more **V<sub>SG</sub>** voltage and consequently conducts more. Beware, this PMOS is upside down, so perhaps you've got to turn your head to see that happening.

In short, we've intuitively deducted a linear relationship **ΔV<sub>IN</sub>** ∼ **I<sub>2</sub>**.

I've also calculated this relationship, and I get the exact same value for **R<sub>TOT</sub>** as before, namely:

[image]

#### 1.3  Resistive value

Let us choose some decent values for **R<sub>1</sub>** and **R<sub>C</sub>**:

**R<sub>1</sub>** = 20kΩ
**R<sub>C</sub>** = 100Ω

With these values, plotting **R<sub>TOT</sub>** against **R<sub>VCR</sub>** gives:

[image]

Let us now plot **R<sub>TOT</sub>** against the control voltage **V<sub>CONTROL</sub>** that drives the VCR resistance on the left. I'm using a VCR circuit based on the LM13700, as explained here: [Floating voltage-controlled resistor with LM13700: How does it work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389347/floating-voltage-controlled-resistor-with-lm13700-how-does-it-work)
Based on those formulas relating **V<sub>CONTROL</sub>** to **R<sub>VCR</sub>** combined with the previous formula relating **R<sub>VCR</sub>** to **R<sub>TOT</sub>**, I get:

[image]

#### 1.4  Notes

Perhaps you've noted the resistors **R<sub>A</sub>** and **R<sub>B</sub>** around the mosfets. The purpose of **R<sub>A</sub>** is to protect the output of the opamp. Opamps don't like capacitive loads that much - depending on one type to another of course.
Mosfets have a "linear region" in which they act as a resistor. However, if you drive the gate just a little too high, you risk to leave that region in an instant. I know that the feedback mechanism should prevent this from happening. But I thought: let's give those opamps some margin. It doesn't hurt to increase artificially that linear region with the resistive divider **R<sub>A</sub>** and **R<sub>B</sub>**.

#### 1.5  Components

These are the parts I'm going to use:

- OPAMP  →  LTC6090 (Digikey: `LTC6090HS8E-5#PBF-ND‎`)
- NMOS   →  IRF740 (Digikey: `IRF740LCPBF-ND‎`) 
                      or STP3LN80K5 (Digikey: `497-17293-ND`)
- PMOS   →  IRF6218 (Digikey: `  IRF6218PBF-ND‎`) 
                      or FQP3P20 (Digikey: `FQP3P20-ND`)
- Schottky  →  BAT46 (Digikey: `BAT46-TR`) <sub>Note: Some in parallel for higher current</sub>

---

## 2.  Increase the range

The example in the previous paragraph provided a range from 100Ω to 140Ω. Not so spectacular. This low-range problem has to do with the resistive division at **R<sub>1</sub>** and **R<sub>VCR</sub>**. Even tuning their values doesn't really solve the low-range problem (I believe).

I've introduced an instrumentation amplifier to solve the problem:

[image]

According to my calculations, the relation **R<sub>TOT</sub>** ∼ **R<sub>VCR</sub>** is now:

[image]

with **G** the gain of the amplifier set by resistor **R<sub>G</sub>**. This gain can range from 1 to 1000.

#### 2.1  **R<sub>TOT</sub>** plotted against **V<sub>CONTROL</sub>**

We'll choose the same values for **R<sub>1</sub>** and **R<sub>C</sub>** as before:

**R<sub>1</sub>** = 20kΩ
**R<sub>C</sub>** = 100Ω

For now, we keep the gain at **G** = 1. This is now **R<sub>TOT</sub>** in function of the control voltage:

[image]

You can see a big range on the resistance value: from 100Ω to 225Ω. The range almost doubled, and we didn't even use the potential offered by the gain factor in the instrumentation amplifier.

#### 2.2  Using the potential of the gain

Using the "potential offered by the gain factor" from the instrumentation amplifier could intuitively extend the range. However, that is not really the case.

Let us increase the gain a little to **G** = 1.5. This is what we get:

[image]

Just applying the formula would gives the dashed lines. But they are not representative anymore once **R<sub>TOT</sub>** dives under the value of **R<sub>C</sub>**. **R<sub>TOT</sub>** can never go below that resistance.

The range doesn't extend. Instead, it shifts downwards and gets tighter. So we have to keep the gain **G** = 1!

---

## 3.  My question

I've got a couple of questions concerning this circuit:

- Is the way I'm using the PMOS okay? It's upside down...
- Do you see another option (instead of inserting an instrumentation amplifier) to increase the range of **R<sub>TOT</sub>**?
- Do you see any other issues in the circuit?

I'm going to build the circuit in a few days on a PCB, and would like to catch errors early before spending a lot.

Comment: What specs for Vcr vs R? And tolerances or acceptance criteria?

Comment: Hi @TonyEErocketscientist, you can find the specs of the R_VCR (the voltage controlled resistor on the left) here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389347/floating-voltage-controlled-resistor-with-lm13700-how-does-it-work.

Comment: Simulate before building it.

Comment: Hi @Andyaka, I would like to do that. But currently, I have two main drawbacks when it's about simulating electronic circuits: (1) Costs: For the moment, I cannot afford expensive simulation software. (2) Time investment: learning to use simulation software requires time and efforts. The past few years, I've been focusing mostly on embedded software design, and didn't need to build many PCB's. Nonetheless, I'd like to take on more circuit-building-projects over the next years, so investing time in learning software might be a good idea. What software do you advise?

Comment: Micro cap student edition is free. Yes there’s a learning curve but it is 100% worth it.

Comment: So what was the result once you built the PCB? Can you answer your own question @K.Mulier?

Comment: LM13700 is not a very accurate part for DC applications, so tread with caution there. Also, its output range leaves something to be desired.

Comment: For modelling: I’m running TI’s LM13700 model in LTspice (free to download) without major issues. Your LTC opamp should be in the built-in libraries as well. I think you would find it worth the effort to simulate this before building

Answer (score 1):

> Is the upside down PMOS okay?

Yes, it act as a reverse-polarity "diode": https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/525249/59133

> Another option (instead of inserting an instrumentation amplifier) to increase the range of RTOT?

I don't see a biasing method that you haven't already graphed and explored.

> Any other issues in the circuit?

You tell us. I'm assuming you built the circuit in the few days since you said, and it's been almost three years since.