# OTA LTSpice model help

Tags: ltspice, ota

(This is my first post go easy on me)

I'm trying to use an OTA to simulate a floating voltage controlled resister like explained [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389347/floating-voltage-controlled-resistor-with-lm13700-how-does-it-work), but I cannot for the life of me figure out how the mota model functions.

I'm aware of the general idea of an OTA. Differential input, biasing current multiplier, etc. But I cannot get the model in LTspice to function properly. I thought at first that I was supposed to connect a voltage to the bottom left I/O pin, but then I figured out it was a ground reference...

I'm having trouble getting any output from the OTA, and the current doesn't seem to be entering the biasing input.

Any and all help would be appreciated!

[image: LTspice Simulation]

Green V(n010): Differential voltage measured from negative input to positive input

Blue V(n015): Output node of OTA

Red I(R10): Current through R10 (supposedly biasing output current, but not working)

Comment: What parameters have you passed to the OTA? See [this](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Undocumented_LTspice#OTA) for more info, if in doubt. Also, `R10` is useless, the pin does not draw current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the `ota`, then maybe you are not looking for a real-life case, instead, you want a behavioural model. If so, the simplest voltage dependent resistor is the behavioural resistor:

```
R1 nodeA nodeB R=f( V(control) )
```

where `V(control)` is the controlling voltage and `f(x)` is an optional function of your choice. Being a behavioural element, it has advantages and disadvantages.

Another approach, a bit more involved, but without the behavioural resistor, is using this:

[image: alt]

The circuit on the left is the "engine": `Iref` generates a unity current over `S1` (a VCSW), generating a voltage. This is then compared with a reference voltage, `Vref`, who represents the desired time varying resistance. The difference goes through an error amplifier and a loop filter (`Gfb` and `Cfb`), generating a controlling voltage for the switch. This voltage can control any other switch in the schematic (like `S2`) that needs a varying resistance as supplied by `Vref`.

It's not perfect, either: the bandwidth is limited by the time constant of `Cfb` and its series resistance (1 \$\Omega\$, thus only `Cfb`'s value matters -- `Rpar` is there just for a DC path to ground), the on/off values of the switche's resistances are the lower/upper limits of its variance, and, not lastly, the number of elements/nodes. OTOH, it's blazingly fast, despite this last shortcoming.

As for the `OTA`, here are three ways to use it, based on various parameter settings:

[image: ota]

`A1` uses `iout`, which means symmetric, `tanh()` limited output (black trace), `A2` uses different `isrc` and `isink` for asymmetric, `tanh()` limited output (blue trace), and `A3` uses the `linear` flag, which means that any voltage going beyond the limits will have the gain halved (red trace). All are compared to the normal `V(a)*V(b)` (gren trace).

Comment: Thank you! I found the list of parameters for OTA's on the wiki and added the few you had in A2.